# Accessing buttons created in another file - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button in a function declared in an external javascript file. With the html file (in some sense the "main" file), I am trying to access this button and assign click listeners. I am not able to do so. Please see below for the code I have so far.

`testDialogJS.js`:

```
/**
 * The JS here will be referenced from another file.
 */

function creator() {

  console.log("creator.");
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var text = document.createTextNode("Click me!");
  btn.setAttribute("id", "Button");
  btn.appendChild(text);
}
```

`testDialog.html:`

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
.hlight{background-color:#ffcc00; }
textarea {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="testDialogJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {

  console.log("Window has been loaded.");
  creator();   //this function is elsewhere.

  var btn = document.getElementById("Button");
  if(btn == null) {
    console.log("Button is null.");
  } else {
    console.log("Button is not null.");
    btn.onclick=function() {
      console.log("Hello.");
    }
  }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you appended that button to the document?

Comment: @Arvind: You were right. I had not appended the button to the document. If you can write your answer, I will be happy to mark it as correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not `appended` your `button` to the `document`. So this returns `null` when you try to select the button using  `document.getElementById("Button")`

Add the following statement in `creator()` like this

```
function creator() {

  console.log("creator.");
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var text = document.createTextNode("Click me!");
  btn.setAttribute("id", "mybtn");
  btn.appendChild(text);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zFlsZOTLd34nfoooZV59?p=preview)